# I am using hashes in my url but then my back button is broken

Tags: javascript, html

On my website I have some javascript which changes the URL by adding # and some information as the user takes some action.

for example:

```
www.mysite.com/index.html#shoes=23,books=12
www.mysite.com/index.html#shoes=24,books=12
```

The website works brilliantly but the back button appears to be broken
When the user presses back I don't want to move back to my previous values on the url with the hash but I really want to go back, like moving away from the page.

Can somebody help ?

Comment: That's 1 of the reasons you would use the pound sign :P

Comment: Doctor, Doctor, it hurts when I do this. So don't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a feature of the browser: visiting a new URL with a hash is a separate history item. You will not be able to solve this without changing how you handle URLs. From a UI perspective, this seriously makes sense. Imagine if gmail didn't do this (like in the old days). The user experience would be significantly diminished.

Unless this breaks your app, I suggest you leave it as it is; your users will thank you for it.